# Android - Unzip SystemUI to modify the files within

Tags: java, android, themes, unzip

So, I asked a question earlier today about a similar topic, and got my answer. But now I have another question...
I've seen apps(rootbox is one of them) that can unzip your SystemUI.apk and then replace the images inside(like the battery images, the wifi images, the 4g images, ect.) So I wanted to make a small app like that. That'll theme your device. Now I've made most of the app. The whole layout is down, everything works fine, except for one thing... The installation. I cannot seem to be able to unzip the SystemUI.Apo, replace certain files, and then rezip, install, ect. The battery mod, wifi mod, ect., are basically a zip file that you download. Within them they have a res folder. Inside the res folder are more folders, and inside those folders are the images. So I have, for example, res/drawable-hdpi/images.png. So I just need to copy those files into the systemUI folders. I have tried a few times, all using scripts. I tried unziping the mod and systemUI, and then copying the files into the systemUI, but I cannot unzip the systemUI.apk.(I guess unzip can't unzip apks) I also tried copying the systemUI.apk and then zipped the systemUI.apk with the res folder containing my mods, but that didn't work either(bootloop). I am lost now. My question is simple: How do I unzip the systemUI, replace the files needed, and then resupply, chmod 644 it, ect. I hope I didn't annoy you guys with my silly question. Thanks for reading! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have root, what you ask for is impossible.

Assume that you have root on your device, in order to achieve that, you may try:

- pull the SYstemUI.apk file
- use [apktool](http://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/) to decompile the apk
- replace the images with yours
- use apktool to recompile the apk
- use a root brower to replace SystemUI.apk with the modified one

Comment: Yes I do have root. And I have themes the SystemUI before. Sorry if I wasn't clear. I need to do this within my app. Maybe using scripting.

Comment: in that case, you may want look into apktool, see how they do the unpacking and signing of the apk file

Comment: Thanks. I got it using the following code in a shell script: zip -r SystemUI.apk res

Comment: Is this really doable? Doesn't SystemUI.apk needs signing with the same key as the framework or something like that??

Answer (score 0):

[Apktool](http://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/) is a good tool for decompiling and recompiling APKs, Your devices must be rooted, or you can edit your ROM and flash it back.

here's a good link explaining how to use android-apktool

[How to EDIT SystemUI.apk/Apps Background](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1714481)